# Nans on pd.factorize return object

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm using the code bellow to encode a data set:

```
foo= pd.DataFrame({
                    'Col1' : ['B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
                    'Val' : np.random.randn(7)
                   })
r=pd.factorize(foo['Col1'], sort=True)
foo['Col1'] = r[0]
```

which produces the following correct result (before\after):

```
  Col1       Val           Col1       Val
    B   0.094336             1   0.094336
    A  -0.422168             0  -0.422168
    B  -0.750304             1  -0.750304
    C   1.910625             2   1.910625
    B   0.921890             1   0.921890
    A   0.422612             0   0.422612
    C  -1.130780             2  -1.130780


print r
(array([1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2]), Index([u'A', u'B', u'C'], dtype='object'))
```

and (because of the "sort") I can also build a mapping function between key\value by running - which is my goal:

```
zip( np.unique(r[0]), r[1])
[(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C')] # A became 0; B became 1 and so on...
```

my problem is when I have nans on the data set and they get -1 (which is exactly what I want - it has to be -1):

```
foo= pd.DataFrame({
                    'Col1' : ['B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', np.nan],
                    'Val' : np.random.randn(7)
                   })

r=pd.factorize(foo['Col1'], sort=True)
foo['Col1'] = r[0]


Col1       Val         Col1       Val
  B  1.397748          1  1.397748
  A -1.011483          0 -1.011483
  B  0.679650          1  0.679650
  C  0.861900          2  0.861900
  B -0.430241          1 -0.430241
  A  1.472984          0  1.472984
NaN  0.549857         -1  0.549857
```

but the pd.factorize is not returning the "nan" on the index:

```
print r[1]
Index([u'A', u'B', u'C'], dtype='object')
```

and now my mapping function doesn't work:

```
zip( np.unique(r[0]), r[1])
Out[148]: [(-1, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (1, 'C')]
```

Any way to make the pd.factorize function return the nan on its index object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since the column contains dtypes of `float`+ `str` in it as a result of `Nans` present in it, `pd.factorize`excludes the missing values after allocating a value of -1(default).

An alternative would be to compute the unique values present in the series and later convert it into `categorical` dtype which also allocates a value of -1 for `Nans` through it's `codes` attribute.

***Demo:***

```
ser = pd.Series(foo['Col1'].unique(), dtype='category')
ser
Out[125]:
0      B
1      A
2      C
3    NaN
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [A, B, C]

print(list(zip(ser, ser.cat.codes)))
#[('B', 1), ('A', 0), ('C', 2), (nan, -1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that the only reason for a `-1` in `r[0]` is `np.nan` in your data set, then you can get the desired mapping with the following function:

```
def get_mapping(r):
    if -1 in r[0]:
         return zip( np.unique(r[0]), r[1].insert(0, np.nan) )
    else:
         return zip( np.unique(r[0]), r[1] )
```